# Azure Search Delete - Is there any way to specify conditions for the delete?

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

I have documents that are "owned" by particular users. The documents have the user id in a "userId" field.

I would like to issue a Delete command for a document, but also specifying conditions, for example (pseudo code) `DELETE WHERE id = @documentId AND userId = @userId`.

Currently the only way I can think to do this is I first issue a search `SELECT WHERE id = @documentId AND userId = @userId`. If I get back a document, then I know the document is owned by the expected user so I issue the delete command `DELETE WHERE id = @documentId`. But that requires two trips on the wire and I would prefer some way to do it in one trip.

Is there any way to do this in one command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, deleting a document is only possible via specifying its id. You seem to be asking for the more general "delete by query" functionality - please vote for [this UserVoice suggestion](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263029-azure-search/suggestions/13792500-possibility-to-delete-documents-that-correspond-to) to help us prioritize this feature. Thanks!